# Can't get my new phone synced with data from old one

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sync

My data (contacts, etc) were synced from my old phone running Android v4.2.1. And now I'm trying to store my data to my new phone with Android 5.0. I've set up my account there, verified that sync is turned on and pressed "sync now". However, absolutely no data appears on the new phone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try going to contacts app and check in its settings if it has some "import" option to import from google synced fonts?

Comment: @Jaskaranbir Singh, I don't see any import option. It has "show contacts from Google" menu, but it's empty.